# Wrapping function around purrr::pmap using column names

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, purrr, nse

I try to write a simple function wrapping around the purrr::pmap_dbl() function.

I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(
          col1 = 1:5, 
          col2 = 2:6, 
          col3 = 3:7
)
```

And the following function:

```
addfn <- function(x, y){
   x^2 + y
}
```

Then I would like to write a function like:

```
testfn <- function(data, a, b){
    purrr::pmap_dbl(data, function(a, b, ...) addfn(a, b))
}
```

Unfortunately, `testfn(df, col1, col2)` gives an error in this case. I would like to obtain the same output as the output obtained by:

```
purrr::pmap_dbl(df, function(col1, col2, ...) addfn(col1, col2))
```

What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) testfn** First, note that using `testfn` from the question that this already works:

```
testfn(unname(df[c("col1", "col3")]))
## [1]  4  8 14 22 32
```

**2) testfn2** and we can modify that to:

```
testfn2 <- function(data, ...) {
  data %>% select(...) %>% unname %>% purrr::pmap_dbl(addfn)
}

testfn2(df, col1, col3)
## [1]  4  8 14 22 32

testfn2(df, "col1", "col3")
## [1]  4  8 14 22 32
```

**3) base R** Of course as has been pointed out we don't really need purrr for this.  This works in base R because `addfn` is vectorized:

```
with(df, addfn(col1, col3))
## [1]  4  8 14 22 32
```

or if `addfn` were not vectorized then:

```
with(df, mapply(addfn, col1, col3))
## [1]  4  8 14 22 32
```

and we could write this function using standard evaluation:

```
testfn3 <- function(data, a, b) mapply(addfn, df[[a]], df[[b]])

testfn3(df, "col1", "col3")
## [1]  4  8 14 22 32
```

or using non-standard evaluation:

```
testfn4 <- function(data, ...) eval.parent(substitute(
  with(data, mapply(addfn, ...))
))

testfn4(df, col1, col3)
## [1]  4  8 14 22 32
```

Answer (score 4):

You can select into your df before using it in map:

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
testfn <- function(data, x, y){
  data <- select(data, !!enquo(x), !!enquo(y))
  pmap_dbl(data, ~ addfn(.x, .y))
}

testfn(df, col1, col3)
```

Comment: This is a nice work around. However, I would like to know whether it is possible to call the column names directly.

Comment: One of the main objectives of using `tidyverse` (e.g. `dplyr` and `purrr`) is to have a code that is easy to follow. I can't see how @ColinFAY 's is improving in that regard compared to the `base` R packages, see comment by akrun below.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use `apply` functions.

```
addfn <- function(x){
  apply(x,1,function(y) y[1]^2 + y[2])
}

addfn(df[,1:2])
[1]  3  7 13 21 31

addfn(df[,2:3])
[1]  7 13 21 31 43
```

Comment: If you are using `base R` methods, then `x[,1]^2 + x[,2]` would be more compact and faster

Comment: Of course, but it seemed like the topic starter wanted specifically a function. But I might have misunderstood.